# Electron forge: forge.config for icon

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to follow the documentation to change the app's icon when start make but the app is built with a default icon or get an error 'Fatal error: Unable to set icon' (if add to new MakerSquirrel ({ setupIcon:'images/icon.png' })).

```
  electron
     images
       icon.png
     src
       ...
       index.ts
     forge.config.ts
     package.json
     ...
```

forge.config:

```
 const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {
    icon: 'images/icon', // no file extension required
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [new MakerSquirrel({}), new MakerZIP({}, ['darwin']), new MakerRpm({}), new MakerDeb({})],...}
```

index.ts

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
    icon: '../images/icon.png',
  });

app.whenReady().then(() => {
 createWindow();

const path = `${app.getAppPath()}/images/icon.png`;

const image = nativeImage.createFromPath(path);

image.setTemplateImage(true);

  new TrayMenu(path);
});
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
```

I spent a lot of time searching for the problem, but I did not find anything
Tried to change path to path.resolve(__dirname, 'images/icon.png'), path.join  and other.

If i run app that is not built (npm run start), then the icon is displayed

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

convert your icon.png to a icon.ico with one of the many online ico-online-converters.

https://www.electronforge.io/guides/create-and-add-icons

for the forge config the path can stay relative.
But for the browserwindow make sure you use absolute path and not relative paths, otherwise it may only work in development mode but not in the packaged app

```
import * as path from 'path';
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  icon: path.join(__dirname, "../images/icon.ico"),
});
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't work

Comment: hm strange. I use it like that in my code and it works.